# Getting different results while computing md5 for Serializable object vs string

Tags: java, md5

I want to compute md5 of any Serilizable object, which is done by following function.

```
public static String getMd5Hash(Serializable object) {
        try {
            return getChecksum(object, "MD5");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RmsException("Exception while generating md5 hash", e);
        }
    }



public static String getMd5Hash(Serializable object) {
            try {
                return getChecksum(object, "MD5");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Exception while generating md5 hash", e);
            }
        }

    private static String getChecksum(Serializable object, String algorithm)
        throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        try (
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)
        ) {
            oos.writeObject(object);
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
            byte[] theDigest = md.digest(baos.toByteArray());
            return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(theDigest);
        }
    }
```

Test

```
@Test
 public void getMd5Hash() {
        String actual = CryptoUtils.getMd5Hash("water");

        Assert.assertEquals("9460370bb0ca1c98a779b1bcc6861c2c", actual);
}
```

OP

```
Expected :9460370bb0ca1c98a779b1bcc6861c2c (actual md5 for string water)
Actual   :37F7DBD142DABF05ACAA6759C4D9E96C (Why the diff?)
```

Comment: What is you input to **getChecksum** method ?

Comment: Its getChecksum(SerializiableObject, "MD5"); Check getMd5Hash method above. I forgot to post that method before.

Comment: It is hard to say what CryptoUtils.getMd5Hash is doing, as I cannot find the docs for it. What if you got the byte array from "water" by serializing it. Then get the hash from that. Possibly the other algorithm is using String.getBytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Terje says,

ObjectOutPutStream adds a header, you can verify that using

```
public static String getChecksum(Serializable object, String algorithm)
            throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)) {

            oos.writeObject(object);
            oos.flush();
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
            md.update(object.toString().getBytes());
            byte[] theDigest = md.digest();
            System.out.println("Without Object output stream="+DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(theDigest));


            md.reset();
            System.out.println("object="+object+ " Written to ByteArray is="+baos.toString());
            md.update(baos.toByteArray());
            theDigest = md.digest();
            return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(theDigest);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        System.out.println(getChecksum("water", "MD5")); 

    }
```

Instead of creating all ByteArrayOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream, you can simple use

```
md.update(object.toString().getBytes());
```

To write byte array to MessageDigest.

Thanks

Comment: I want this utility to take hash of  any java object, not only string. I then use it to dedupe object by contents. I have some complex use case. The goal is to dedupe objects by its contents.

Answer (score 2):

The `ObjectOutputStream` adds a header, so the `Serializable` you are passing does not actually represent "water" when you get the byte array. Print out `baos.toString()` to verify. You can either extend `ObjectOutputStream` and override the `writeStreamHeader` method, or call `md.digest` with the substring of the data, ie `md.digest(baos.substring(7).getBytes())` (or something thereabouts). Once the actual data digested is "water", the hash will be correct.